# implementing a manual hasNext() function

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am trying to find a similar manual code to StringTokenizer.hasNextToken() to iterate over the input and also storing the input in an ArrayList.

I have tried to implement a count in my Reader class but it ends up counting each characters and not the integers.

```java
int nextInt() throws Exception{
        int integer = 0;
        int neg = 1;
        int n = scan();
        while(isWhiteSpace(n)) n=scan();
        if(n == '-'){
            neg = -1;
            n = scan();
        }
        while(!isWhiteSpace(n)){
            if(n>='0' && n<='9'){
                integer *=10;
                integer +=n-'0';
                n=scan();
            }
            else throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
        return neg*integer;
    }
```

My scan function is as follows:

```java
int scan() throws Exception{
        if(total<0) throw new InputMismatchException();
        if(index >= total){
            index = 0;
            total = is.read(buf); //'is' is InputStream type and buf is byte[].
            if(total <= 0) return -1;
        }
        return buf[index++];
    }
```

Input: [1 2 3 4 5]
I expect to populate an ArrayList with:

```java
while(input.hasNext()){
arr.add(input.nextInt());} //arr is ArrayList<Integer> type
```

the array list must have the input as 1 2 3 4 5.
**Note: the input is of variable length.**

Comment: @takendarkk I want to create a hasNext() method explicitly.

Comment: @khelwood I want hasNext() to return a Boolean. If the end of input is reached then it must return false otherwise true.